# How to compare a value to a list of pairs in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, boolean-expression

I need to create a list that is *n* long where each item is a Boolean. The item will only be True when *x* is in the range of one or more pairs of integers. For example, my current code is as follows:

```
l = [True if a < x < b or c < x < d else False for x in range(n)]
```

My issue is that the number of pairs will vary, so only *a* and *b* might exist in one instance, but *e* and *f* could also exist in another. If I were to structure my coordinate pairs in a list of tuples like so...

```
coordinates = [(a,b), (c,d), ...]
```

...is there a way to still do this as a list comprehension? If not, what would be the most pythonic approach?

Comment: `True if <condition> else False` is the same as just the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a generator expression inside `any` to accomplish this:

```
coordinates = [(2, 4), (3, 8)]
n = 5

l = [any(a < x < b for (a, b) in coordinates) for x in range(n)]

print(l)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [False, False, False, True, True]
> ```